# Marvelous designer alembic export and textures

Tags: texturing, cloth-simulation, cache, alembic

I have a problem with marvelous designer and alembic export. I just "baked" my cloth animation in Marvelous Designer 10 and exported it as an alembic (ogawa). When I import my alembic file in blender, it fits my avatar but I don't see any textures. I tried to find some tutorials on the internet but it seems that everyone using alembic export from MD to blender don't want the textures. The thing is that I need them. I tried exporting as an obj with a mdd cache with the same project but I don't like the look because there's some weird spots and also it doesn't fit my avatar for an unknown reason. But, the textures are there. So, there's the questions:

1. Can I transfer the cache from the alembic file to the obj file to make it fit my avatar?
2. Is there a way to texture the alembic file like the obj file to have textures on my alembic?

Thank you.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/92768

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, I tested it today. The important trick is to make sure that you import the OBJ with the option to "preserve vertex order" under geometry drop down on the right side in 2.92 - the default in Blender import is a split. You can then assign then either an MDD cache, a PC2 cache (both exportable from MD) via the mesh cache modifier. Or you can assign an Alembic cache (the .abc file) via the Mesh Sequence modifier (instead of importing the Alembic - which creates the basic untextured mesh for you I assume).

In all circumstances you have to change some of the axis information depending on how you exported from MD (e.g. in mesh cache, Y-up and Z-forward, and mirror X... worked for me). With the Alembic you might have to rotate the object as such instead as the modifier does not support axis changes.

Note that in PC2 it might also be that you have to change the FPS impact on the timeline as well in the modifier.

And make sure you export from MD in scale for meters - else your mesh is not the right size (but you can scale I guess).

What does not work for me for some reason is FBX from MD back into Blender with animation. Not sure why this is messed up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried to import my stuff with both mdd and pc2 cache but it seems that they both have the same bug: their movements don't fit with my model. But, when I use the alembic cache, it's weirder. it looks like it doesn't fits or something? I made a video to explain better: https://youtu.be/iF260cTVic4
Also, I did check if the avatar was the same. And I checked keep vertex order too.

Comment: The problem with MD's alembic export is that it always exports all your patterns as a single mesh. It makes texturing rather difficult. MDD cache seems to work without this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

I work in C4D so I also export an OBJ with all the texture UV'S as well as the alembic. then I import the abc and the obj back to C4D and manually copy the texture UV's back to the mesh.
Labour intensive but it works in C4D.